# AngularJS - multiple Google maps not loading

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-google-maps

I'm developing an app (in my local machine) which displays various locations (an array that varies in size) in an accordion. I'm using the accordion and pagination directives from [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) with the Google Maps JS API-based directives from [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).

I have an issue where sometimes the map loads in the first item I clicked, then I click on another item in the accordion and the map doesn't load. Then a few minutes later, I'll refresh my browser and I click on the same item and the map will load. Then if I go to another page in the pagination, the maps aren't displayed there. As you can see in my code, I'm only calling the maps when I click on an item in the accordion, not when the items are loaded. I don't want a lot of maps to be loaded right away if the size of the locations array is large.

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gUaNVbPE4coVWnrAWuKd?p=preview) demonstrating the problem, and here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/7m4oLxo8/).

Here is some code from the example linked above which I think is important to the problem:

#### HTML body

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="location in locations | startFrom: (currentPage-1)*5| limitTo: 5">
        <accordion-heading >
            <strong get-map-dir location-index={{$index}}>Location</strong> - {{location.address1}}
        </accordion-heading>
        <div id="branch_map" class="" ng-show="showMap ">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center='location.mapInfo.map.center' zoom='location.mapInfo.map.zoom'>
                <ui-gmap-marker coords="location.mapInfo.marker.coords" options="location.mapInfo.marker.options" idkey="location.mapInfo.marker.id">
                    <ui-gmap-window ng-cloak closeClick="closeClick()">
                    </ui-gmap-window>
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>

    <pagination total-items="locations.length" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-hide="locations.length < itemsPerPage"></pagination>
</accordion>
```

#### JS (partial)

```
  .factory('anotherService', function() {
    //getMap using google-maps directive from angularjs-ui
    var getMap = function(locationObj, outerCallBack) {
      console.info('get map');
      var mapInfo = {};
      var address = locationObj.address1;
      var zoom = 16;
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      console.log(locationObj);

      geocoder.geocode({
        "address": address, //required
        "region": 'CA' //CA for canada
      }, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {

          var location = results[0].geometry.location,
            lat = location.lat(),
            lng = location.lng();

          mapInfo.map = {
            center: {
              latitude: lat,
              longitude: lng
            },
            zoom: zoom
          };

          mapInfo.marker = {
            id: 0,
            coords: {
              latitude: lat,
              longitude: lng
            },
            options: {
              title: address
            }

          };
          outerCallBack({
            success: true,
            mapInfo: mapInfo
          });

        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          console.info("Geocoder was sucessful but has no results");
          console.info("address =" + address);
          return;
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          console.error("You are over your query limit");
          console.info("address =" + address);
          return;
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.REQUEST_DENIED) {
          console.error("Your request has been denied by Geocoder");
          return;
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.INVALID_REQUEST) {
          console.error("Invalid Geocoder request");
          return;
        } else {
          console.error("Google Maps in Ctrl failed");
          console.error("address  =" + address);
          return;
        }

      });


    };

    var anotherService = {
      getMap: getMap
    };
    return anotherService;
  })

.directive('fetchMap', function($timeout, anotherService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      console.log("get map dir");
      console.log(scope);
      console.log(elem);
      console.log(attrs);
      elem.bind('click', function(event) {
        //   console.clear();
        console.log("You clicked on me");
        console.log(scope.locations[attrs.locationIndex].mapInfo);

        if (angular.isUndefined(scope.locations[attrs.locationIndex].mapInfo)) {
          anotherService.getMap(scope.locations[attrs.locationIndex], function(callBackfunc) {
            console.info("Getting maps");
            //  scope.showPreloader = false;
            scope.locations[attrs.locationIndex].mapInfo = callBackfunc.mapInfo;
            $timeout(function() {
              scope.showMap = true;
            }, 2000);

          });
        }

      });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: where's your ng-click logic?

Comment: I'm using a directive getMapDir then binding the 'click' event. Dont think i need a ng-cilck logic

Comment: This is a good reference for you: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/two-maps.html.

Comment: I've looked at that but sadly it doesnt help. I can display 5 maps but anything more than 5, I dont get any maps at all.

Comment: I think this doesn't have much to do with map but bootstrap's handling of multiple instances from what I've come across so far. I will get back to you if I find a solution for that.

Comment: @KayAnn I've managed to get a jsfiddle up. Please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/7m4oLxo8/ . The first 5 locations has the map loaded. However when clicking on a page, the map on the displayed 5 locations no longer works. Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you want to try putting these instances in accordion? Here's an example: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion. I would try it but I don't have much experience with bootstrap, don't want to give a broken example. :)